Divisibility: how to determine the last digit(s) for when  is of form of $2^{k} 5^{m}$?
Let me clarify first that I am not allowed to check for number divisibility by a certain n by simply checking if the remainder is zero.
What I want to do is basically determine digit(s) that a numbers must ends with in order to be divisible by n.
Let's say n is either:

$2^{k}$
$5^{m}$
$2^{k} * 5^{m}$

where k=3 and m =2.
My questions are:

How to determine the number of last digits necessary to check divisibility? I thought of taking the largest exponent and pretty much using it to determine how many last digits are necessary for checking divisibility but it doesn't always work because, for instance: 200 = $2^{3} * 5^{2}$ and we need as a matter of fact 3 digits to check divisibility by 200. However 400 = $2^{4} * 5^{2}$ and we still need 3 digits to check divisibility by 400 instead of the expected 4 digits.

For merely $2^{k}$ or $5^{m}$ I think the last digits would need to be merely multiples of that number, correct? So for 2 it will be {0,2,4,6,8}, for 4 it will be {0,4,8,12,16,20,24,...}, for 8 it will be {0,8,16,24,32,40,48,...}, for 5 it will be {0,5} (which would be pretty much {0,5,10,15,20,25,30,...}) and for 25 it will be {00,25,50,75}. Correct? Instead for $2^{k} * 5^{m}$ we would pretty much need to intersect the sets of digits that denote the last digit(s) for each prime factor? So for a number like 20 the set would be {00,20,40,60,80}. For 40, 80, 200 and 400 what would those sets be?


Thank you to whoever is going to explain this to me.

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule.  Think about what is says about $4$ because it is $2^2$.

"we still need 3 digits to check divisibility by 400" -- How? 1400 and 2400 have the same last three digits, but only one is divisible by 400.

@RossMillikan I did. What part exactly? There are three parts for 4.

@DavidK so we need indeed 4 digits? If so, taking the largest exponent denotes the  number of final digits required to check divisibility?

$m=d\cdot  10^j$ for $,d = 2^i,$ or $,5^i.,$ $,m,$ divides $,a\cdot 10^j + b,$ iff $,b = 0,$ and $,d\mid a, $ $ (!\iff! d\mid a\bmod 10^i),\ $ so we've reduced to testing divisibility by powers of $,2,$ or $,5.\ \ $
